# WCF MetaData when to enable

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I am currently trying to get my head around WCF services and have come to a bit of a roadblock in regards to metadata.

I have been doing some research and from what I am reading I have come to the understanding that metadata should only be enabled if necessary, as it increases the attack surface for the service. At the same time though it seems as if it is instrumental in their operation.

Now my question is what is metadata's role in WCF services, and how do I know when it is appropriate to enable metadata?

I have been on [MSDNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731823%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but there explanation is a bit cryptic, can anyone explain it differently?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rule of thumb, the only time you need meta data exposed is during development and testing stages.

The meta data as described on the MDSN page.

> The Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) provides an infrastructure
>   for exporting, publishing, retrieving, and importing service metadata.
>   WCF services use metadata to describe how to interact with the
>   service's endpoints so that tools, such as Svcutil.exe, can
>   automatically generate client code for accessing the service.

This simply means, the metadata provides mechanisms for tools to auto-generate the classes and methods required to interact with the service.

In the case of Visual Studio the meta data is only used when you either `Add the Service Reference` or `Update Service Reference`. Visual Studio will request the meta data from the WCF service and build \ update the artifacts required to interact with the service.

During normal execution the Meta Data is not requested as the artifacts are already built and understand how to interact with the service.

However if you change the service schema at all the meta data must be turned back on so you can update the service reference.

There are other places that the Meta Data are requested. As stated in the description Svcutil.exe" and programs such as the WCF tester application.

Hope this helps.